# How to point subdomain of A to folder of domain B

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain

I have a subdomain, say `sub.A.com`

I would like this to be pointed to `B.com/folder`

With `A.com` I am only able to change the DNS records since it's hosted on an eCommerce platform.

With `B.com` I can change any parameter since I host it.

A simple `301` redirect from `sub.A.com` won't do because I don't want people to see `B.com` when they go to `sub.A.com`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have full control over B.com, you could do this:

1. Point the subdomain `sub.A.com` to the IP of `B.com` in the DNS A-record (and AAAA-record, if you use IPv6).
2. Add a virtual Host, server name alias or whatever is appropriate at the server for `B.com` that delivers the content from folder `${DocumentRoot of B.com}/folder` when a request for `sub.A.com` comes in.